# stream.Transform accept new input before completing output

Tags: node.js, stream

I am implementing a Transform stream with an async manipulation. Mine is called `Parser`.

```
var Transform = require('stream').transform;

function Parser(options) {
  Transform.call(this, {objectMode: true});
}

Parser.prototype._transform = function _transform(input, encoding, callback) {
  var this_ = this;
  doSomethingAsync(input, function(output) {
    this_.push(output);
    //possible location #1 for callback();
  });
  //possible location #2 for callback();
}
```

Each incoming chunk may potentially take a long time to process (`doSomethingAsync` requires a network request). However, each chunk is processed completely independently of the chunk before. Moreover, the exact order of the outputs is not important. Each output contains a descriptor that  identifies its input, rather than being identified by order.

Therefore, I would like `_transform` to be called again as soon as possible, rather than waiting until the given chunk is completely done processing. So, looking at the code, if I put `callback()` in `possible location #1`, then `_transform` is never called until each chunk is completely processed. But if I put it in `possible location #2`, then my stream is pushing after the callback, which results in these unsightly

```
Uncaught Error: stream.push() after EOF
```

errors once the stream terminates.

So my question: is it possible to do this with a transform stream? Or should I look into using a library? If so, which genre (event-stream, FRP, etc...)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement `_flush()` on your stream and only call the callback passed to that function when all of your async functions complete. Something like this:

```
function Parser(options) {
  Transform.call(this, {objectMode: true});

  this._pending = 0;
  this._flushcb = undefined;
}

Parser.prototype._transform = function _transform(input, encoding, callback) {
  var self = this;

  ++this._pending;

  doSomethingAsync(input, function(output) {
    self.push(output);
    if (--self._pending === 0 && self._flushcb)
      self._flushcb();
  });

  callback();
}

Parser.prototype._flush = function(callback) {
  this._flushcb = callback;
};
```

Comment: Excellent - I hadn't thought of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is not complete.
Imagine you have a `_transform()` like this:

```
_transform(chunk, encoding, done) {
    let data = chunk.toString();
    this.rest += data;
    [this.toPush, this.rest] = this.f(this.rest);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.toPush.length; i++) {
        if (!this.push(this.toPush[i])) {
            this._source.readStop();
            break;
        } 
    }
    done()
}
```

```

where `f` is, for instance, a function spliting the received chunk in paragraphs. `rest` is something at the end of the chunk `f` cannot determine if it is an entire paragraphe, and thus expects more data (another chunk). When everything has been read one can assume `rest` is an entire paragraph, and then `_flush` is used to push it  as below. The exception described above is thrown, likely because `"<p>"+this.rest+"</p>"`is greater then `this.rest`. It's not really the expected behavior...

```
 _flush(done) {
    if (this.rest !== "") this.push("<p>"+this.rest+"</p>");
    this.rest = null;
    this.toPush = null;
    done()

 }
```

**EDIT:**
So Calvin Metcalf gave me a work around  herehttps://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream/issues/207: on node 8.0.0 one can use _final instead of _flush.
The problem seems quite erratic as he didn't reproduce in his environment.